# MVC 3 website installation issues. Receiving 403 forbidden error after installing MVC 3 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I've come to a point where I am not sure why Godaddy is giving me 403 (Access denied) errors when trying to access an uploaded MVC 3 website.

My Godaddy IIS configuration is as follows:

- IIS 7
- Integrated Pipeline
- ASP.NET Runtime Version: 2.0/3.0/3.5

Server File Structure:

- [Root]
- bin
- Content
- Scripts
- Views

My bin folder contains the following .DLLs (as mentioned [here](http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/mvc-3/)

```
- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
- System.Web.Helpers.dll
- System.Web.Mvc.dll
- System.Web.Razor.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll
```

I created my MVC 3 application with the basic settings and used the publish deploy method.  The web.config does have the following attribute, but I don't know if this is the error since my account only seems to support up to 3.5 ASP.NET.  But I'm getting a 403 error, so I don't think this is the case:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are targeting the .NET 4 framework. Have you ensured that your IIS 7 application is configured for [.NET 4 as noted here on GoDaddy](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/687)?

Since you stated your IIS site is targeting .NET 3.5, but the app web.config is calling for .Net 4.0 you're more than likely getting an error due to this (and GoDaddy is hiding the true error for security reasons).

[ASP.NET MVC3 requires .NET 4.0](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#software-requirements) to run so you'll need to upgrade the framework on GoDaddy using the method above to ensure your site is running .NET 4.

Comment: Okay, when I switched the web project to point to 3.5, I started getting a lot of errors.  It appears that the MVC referenced dll's started causing compile time errors about class names not being found.  Any off-hand ideas?

Comment: @contactmatt Sorry, I will remove that part of my answer. I forgot that MVC 3 requires .NET 4.0 to run.

Answer (score 0):

Did you convert your project to a web app? Right click on project, select "Convert to Web Application".  You may also have to make sure that your web.config file was deployed correctly, as they are sometimes deployed from VS with some sort of crypto that corrupts the web.config file.  Also, check that the permissions of the folder that your app is sitting in has been set to public viewable.